# IF function in time values

Tags: libreoffice

I'm trying to work out how to create formula, to give me value "Yes" or "No" depending on value in certain column. 
I tried IF function =IF(F2>15,G2-E2,"Yes")
*15 is meant to be minutes. If I add 00,15 it doesn't seem to work.

To be more specific, I would like, column to display Yes or No if order been processed in less or more then 15 min.

And then colour it Green,Red, for yes or no. But that's should be easy in condition formatting.

As it's in a time scale, I can't really get it to work.

Comment: What are the values in the column formatted as and what do the values look like?

Comment: I would post a picture, but as a new user I'm not able to. Values would 16:12 in time format.

Comment: Example E2-16:12, G2-16:24. F2=G2-E2.  And h2 would need to display yes or no when F2 is over or under 00:15 minutes. All cells formatted as time HH:MM

Comment: if you want to add a picture to your question, just upload it somewhere (e.g. imgur), then add the link to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time values are a fraction of a day.  To convert to the number of minutes, multiply by 60 minutes per hour and 24 hours per day.

```
=IF(F2*60*24>15,G2-E2,"Yes")
```

**EDIT**:

To show Yes or No:

```
=IF(F2*60*24>15,"No","Yes")
```

Comment: Thank you, that seams to work! Would you be able to tell me how to use "otherwise "No" on the same formula, so it would work properly?

Comment: IF(Test; ThenValue; OtherwiseValue)

Comment: Or can I add another =IF function on the same formula to give "No", if <15? I tried to use IF(Test; ThenValue; OtherwiseValue) getting error message. Doing something wrong.  Sorry for being a pain. Never have been working with these.

Comment: Formula =IF(F2*60*24>15,G2-E2,"Yes", "No") gives me error 504. Tryed to work around wit AND function, can't get it to work.

Comment: `G2-E2` is the ThenValue, but it sounds like that is not what you want.  So instead, write "No" as in my edited response.

Comment: Thank You !! 
=IF(F2*60*24>15,"No","Yes")  This formula works perfectly fine!