# If, and formula, bigger or even

Tags: libreoffice

```
=IF(60*24*(F4+D4)<=15,"Yes","No")
```

How can I fix this line to say that value has to be bigger then 0:01 in time? 
Tried to use AND, but can't get formula right.

[image]

Comment: Sure F4=G4-E4 formatted in time. G4E4(time values entered)

Comment: D4=E4-C4 and again the same.Formated in time, E4C4 is values entered.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, if I'm using formula above, it gives me yes, with no value entered, if I copy the formula down the column.

Comment: https://s29.postimg.org/tezqr4dzr/IMG_1524.jpg Can't really get a good screenshot as I'm on company's PC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `isblank` function to check if the cells have values or not. E.g., this will just return "No" if the cells you're evaluating are empty:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(D4)), NOT(ISBLANK(F4)), 60*24*(F4+D4)<=15), "Yea", "No")
```

Answer (score -1):

`=IF(F4+D4<=1/96,"Yea","No")`

1 hour is 1/24 and 15 min are 1/96.

If you need to copy down the formula but you do not want it to give "y" or "n" (for example you can use "N.A."), you can use:

`=IF(AND(ISBLANK(F4),ISBLANK(D4)),"N.A.",IF(F4+D4<=1/96,"Yea","No"))`

Other answer here: [IF function in time values](https://superuser.com/questions/1153945/if-function-in-time-values)

Comment: Still gives me Yes with blanks. Tried both formulas. I believe it should be in the range between 1 and 15min. To get it to work. Otherwise it assumes anything under 15 minutes is "Yes"